# Efficient way to check the age of the oldest folder with Pathlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I want to find the oldest folder in a directory. There are a lot of folders in the directory. If too old I want to call a separate function that will handle the deletion (not relevant for this question).

Currently I have the following:

```
import pendulum  # just to get a timestamp
from pathlib import Path
def is_cleanup_needed():
    path = "D:\Test"  # Just an example, Linux user please change this
    for folder in path.glob('**/*'):
        folder_age = folder.stat().st_ctime  # Get the time in seconds
        age_in_hours = (pendulum.now().timestamp() - folder_age) / (60 * 60)
        if age_in_hours > 12:  # replace 12 with any hour you want
            return True
    return False
```

The Problem is that this is very inefficient. I have to check every folder. I have a lot of folders. Isn't there a way to just check out the oldest folder?

I just need the single oldest folder, so I want a way to get that without going trough every folder in the path.

**Edit:** It does not have to work with Pathlib as long as it works under windows (7 and 10) and Linux (Ubuntu 18.10)

Comment: You mean inefficient? There really is no way to avoid a `stat` of each file if you need to know their age.

Comment: I only need the oldest folder. Why can't I get the folders sorted by age and limited to just 1 result?

Answer (score 1):

not sure it will be much faster, but here is a sort picking the oldest folder.

```
sorted(path.glob('**/*'), key = lambda x: x.stat().st_ctime)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is nicer then my code but I think that it also checks every folder.

Comment: It will check every folder yes.  I don't think you can avoid that using pathlib.

Comment: It doesn't have to be pathlib. If there is no other way I would use other methods.